# "It is possible that this sentence is not true"

Tags: logic

This is a "modal liar sentence" that I'm trying to use to illustrate how liar sentences are not well-formed. It seems like a nifty species to consider, and I never came across it before, but so... The illustrative feature seems to be a vicious circle where the whole thing becomes, "It is possible that, 'This sentence is possibly not true,' is not true," and so on, just like feeding the liar sentence into the disquotational scheme results in a warp.

But is there an easier analysis in the literature already, that I'm not aware of?

Comment: All of the otherwise undecidable decision problems become decidedly untrue when we construe the body of analytical knowledge as a recursive language with a membership algorithm.  A language L on Σ is said to be recursive if there exists a Turing machine M that accepts L and halts on every w in Σ+. In other words, a language is recursive if and only if there exists a membership algorithm for it. (Linz 1990:288). 

Linz, Peter 1990. An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata. Lexington/Toronto: D. C. Heath and Company.

Comment: I am afraid this illustrates not that Liar sentences are ill formed, but rather that having a truth predicate + self-reference device creates an inconsistent language. The modal Liar can be formulated without the truth predicate, with a necessity/possibility operator only, but even they are truth-like enough to do it, see [Parent, New Modal Liar](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01102).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the "vicious circle". If we imagine different possible versions of a person saying that sentence, this is equivalent to each possible version saying "at least one of my possible selves uttering this sentence is expressing a falsehood". And the analysis of this would seem to be the same as that of a non-modal logic example where we have two or more people, let's say just 2 & call them the Knight and the Knave, who both say something like "at least one of the statements made by the Knight and the Knave is false" (and those are the only statements they utter).

Comment: @Hypnosifl, I don't remember the entirety of my reasoning back then (here), but when I referred to a disquotational warp as an analogical problem, I do remember what I meant: take the base case, "This sentence is not true," is true if and only if this sentence is not true. That isn't a well-formed statement, since the second "this sentence" refers to the example of the disquotational scheme, not the original sentence. So we'd have to say, "This sentence is not true," is not true if and only if *that* sentence is not true.

Comment: Where "that" refers back to the first sentence. But this shows that there is something about the indexical in the liar sentence, that is problematic. The details of that problematique, and its resolution, took me a while to form a stronger belief about (see e.g. my question about ["Let this sentence be false"](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/79608/let-this-sentence-be-false)).

Comment: @Conifold, there appears to have been a recent correction to the cited paper noting that there are some necessitation assumptions being made that aren't being explicitly drawn out.  Do you think your conclusion still holds?

Comment: @PaulRoss I think this only affects exactly how "truth-like" the modal operator needs to be. Parent thought that he could get away without the necessitation rule that Montague's modal liar uses, but, apparently, he could not.

Comment: @KristianBerry , over the Christmas break I'm planning to have another try at JC Beall's "Spandrels of Truth" (https://philpapers.org/rec/BEASOT). Beall was motivated by Relevance logic considerations (e.g. Curry's paradox) to develop some weaker modal logics, and in "Spandrels" he tries to consider disquotational truth in this context and came to the conclusion that there are some semantic artifacts that make the logic awkward but that we ought to just accept that there are some purely semantic truth gaps/gluts.  This might be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is true, but not necessarily so.

It seems clear *prima facie* that a statement whose truth value you cannot really know might be something other than true.  And that the mere *possibility* of it being something other than true does not imply that it is not actually true. Not everything that is possible, happens.  (Note that you have chosen 'not true' and not 'false'.  In the realm of modality, those are not necessarily equivalent.  A proposition that depends on your moral stance might, when asked in general be neither true nor false.)

If you assume that you know it is false, you have a direct contradiction, because the impossible is not possible.  So your option is that either you know it is true, or that you can't really know, so it might not be true, so it is still true.

So the statement is true, but that truth is not necessary -- it remains possible it could be otherwise, or it wouldn't be true in the first place.

What the question forces us to ask, I suppose, is whether what is actual is necessary.  I am coming down on the side (opposite to 
Aristotle) that necessity is a stronger requirement than actuality, so that even what is known to be true for some reason, could still be false in an alternative situation.

There could be a world where only what is necessary is true.  In such a world, the modality of necessity and possibility vanishes, (at the expense of a lot of things being meaningless.)  So it would devolve down to the original Liar's paradox, which has no truth value.  So it could not be true.  By at least one common definition of possibility, Kripke's, we do not live in that world, because we possess the ability to define coherent fictional worlds.  It is only by this observed incident of our world, which is not necessary, that we can deduce the possibility of the statement's non-truth is not ruled out by the observation of its truth.

Unfortunately, that is hard to make clear.  Formalizing it involves hokey nonsense.  Here are a couple of approaches:

If we stick to the Kripke notion of 'possible', that something is possible if you can imagine a world where it is true.  "It is possible that this sentence is not true." can be true.

Since the whole idea involves reference to text, it involves literal quoting.  We can imagine the possible world where the literal text 'true' means 'interesting' instead of meaning *true*.  We can then imagine that the sentence is uninteresting there, because it is here, at least to me.  So we have found a world in which the sentence, as a piece of text, interpreted there would be true.

So the sentence "It is possible this sentence is not true." is true, if by 'this sentence' you mean the text of the sentence.

If you don't like the focus on the text, another way to look at it is that "It is possible this sentence is not true" means "It is not necessary that the sentence 'It is possible this sentence is not true.' is true."  Well, in at least one logical world, the one where only what is necessary is true, it paradoxical, and therefore not necessarily true.  So it is obviously *not* necessary for it to be *true*.  That means this equivalent sentence is true and therefore the original sentence is true, just not out of necessity.

I will say again here, what I said at the top:

**Note that none of this applies to "It is possible this statement is false."**  If you assume *that* is true, it is false.  If you assume it is false, it is true, so it is false.  If you assume it is neither true nor false, *it cannot be false, so it cannot be true*.  In no case is it not in contradiction with itself.

Any argument that assumes these two statements are related, has not paid enough attention.

Comment: "We can imagine the possible world where the literal text 'true' means 'interesting' instead of meaning true."  By your same reasoning (swapping word labels for semantic meanings) We could build a five mile long brick wall from "one cute little bunny" because "one cute little bunny" is what we call a very huge pile of bricks. Nice try.

Comment: @polcott Mockery is not an argument unless it involves **an actual argument**. "Nice try." The cute bunny does not depend entirely upon its name for existence. "This sentence" means what it means only because of the context in which it appears, and the fact the language *can refer to itself*.  So your objection is not an argument.  If we did not quote "one cute little bunny", using it this way would be a lie.  But 'this sentence' means the **quoted** sentence, which consists of actual sounds or letters.  If it doesn't, then actually propose a credible thing that it **would** refer to...

Comment: I conceded these arguments' 'hokey' quality in the post (which makes your then attacking it tacky at best).  But what is hokey is the idea that all forms of "possible" are created equal and there is a single interpretation of the sentence that can be discussed, to begin with.  If there is one, and this is actually a question, why is this not the right interpretation of possible?  (Not, "please call me stupid", Why, really, is this not it?)

Comment: In my fundamental frame-of-reference semantic meanings are absolute and immutable, thus changing the word labels is a fallacy of equivocation error.

Comment: "I conceded these arguments' 'hokey' quality" I did not reach this point. I stopped on the first error.

Comment: @polcott  Well, imposing your fundamental frame-of-reference is not an argument, either.  And not reading a post before responding to it is simply rude.  Arguments can have branches or multiple forms that fix earlier "errors".  This one has two framings.  Your objection, as stated in your comment, is still completely irrelevant.  What is the semantics of "this sentence" that does not involve the wording of the sentence itself in any way?  And what is magical about 'semantics' that means it cannot change across possible worlds?

Comment: Changing the meaning of the term "true" is basically cheating.

Comment: "So the sentence "It is possible this sentence is not true." is true, if by 'this sentence' you mean the text of the sentence."  No not at all. The sentence does not refer to its text it refers to its own semantic meaning.

Comment: "Well, the sentence is potentially paradoxical, and interpreting it that way does not defy logic." It indicates a semantic error in the sentence.

Comment: Bottom line is that by adding modal logic to the Liar Paradox all that we have done is add extraneous complexity that makes it more difficult to see that the original issues is the same.

Comment: @polcott  And I think your notion of necessity is plain old wrong.  You are assuming that what is currently true is always necessary.  If the sentence does not have at truth value under some interpretations, it is not necessarily false, so it is possibly true.  Bottom line, you just don't consider alternative positions worth actually reading.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107727/discussion-between-hide-in-plain-sight-and-polcott).

Comment: The question asks for analyses in literature, not opinions.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking  I agree, so at first I deleted it.  But let's allow the OP to decide whether this is an answer or not.

Comment: I think it is a good answer, hide_in_plain_sight. It is not "from the literature" directly, but it is indeed INFORMED by the literature, which is more than good enough as a basis for a good response, here.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the premise that this is a "model liar sentence" and with @Polcott's answer as well. Let me explain:

The sentence says "It is possible that this sentence is not true."

So there is two options:

If the sentence is true, it remains: "It is possible that this sentence is not true." As we cannot logically determine this sentence to be true 100% of the time, this sentence is ok.

If the sentence is false, then the sentence would be: "It is not possible that this sentence is not true." Which is equivolent to "This sentence is true," which again works.

Comment: It's "modal", not "model", and it does generate a contradiction, see [Post, Possible Liar](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2214683).

Comment: Yes @Conifold is correct, the added extraneous complexity does not change a thing.

Comment: To apply the link, one has to assume not true == false, which is not reasonable in a modal context.  It surely does not apply in the deontological mode, especially once it intersects the mode of necessity.  Things can be not always immoral, yet not always moral.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this illustrates not that Liar sentences are ill formed, but rather that having a truth predicate + self-reference device creates an inconsistent language. The modal Liar can be formulated without the truth predicate, with a necessity/possibility operator only, but even they are truth-like enough to do it, see Parent, New Modal Liar. – **Conifold**

**The above is a direct quote of Conifold's reply.** I agree with the gist of it except that because it is the Liar Paradox sentence itself that specifies self-reference I disagree:
 **"not that Liar sentences are ill formed".** Liar sentence themselves are ill-formed.